# What is best way to compare int and varchar fields in mysql?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have a two large tables.

In the first table have indexed id field with type int.
In the second table have indexed classId field with type varchar(50).
I need to get all fields from first table which do not have classId in the second.

```
select 
    a.id, a.type, a.path, a.filename
from 
    assets a
where 
    a.type="folder" and 
    concat_ws("", a.path, a.filename) like "/product%" AND
    a.id not in (
        select 
           classId 
        from 
           gridconfigs g 
        where 
           g.type='asset' and
           g.name='Photo Attributes'
    );
```

I am trying to do it in that way but request is executing very slowly.

Any idea?

Comment: Use Not exists... `SELECT * FROM assets A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gridconfigs G WHERE A.ID = G.CLASSID and G.type = 'asset' and G.name = 'Photo Attributes')` Implicit casting should take care of the variance.  not in doesn't handle nulls well.

Comment: Wow! It is works great! Can you explain please why it works match faster than my variant.

Comment: if you look at an execution plan you'll see an in must process every record  to see if a.id = g.classID.  `EXISTS` can early exit once a single instance is found.  If you needed data out of gridconfigs we would use a left join where g.classID is null.  instead of a not exists; but at a bit slower of a run.  Also in does not process NULLS correctly whereas not exists will. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500646/which-is-faster-not-in-or-not-exists

Comment: and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: note: implicit casting is occuring to allow these joins to occur.  If you want /need even better performance insure they are the same data types and both have indexes.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the datatypes and indexes.

Comment: I find perfect is the enemy of done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Not exists... or if you need data from gridconfigs use a left join where g.classID is null

```
SELECT * 
FROM assets A 
WHERE a.type="folder" 
  AND  concat_ws("", a.path, a.filename) like "/product%" 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1 
       FROM gridconfigs G 
       WHERE A.ID = G.CLASSID 
         and G.type = 'asset' 
         and G.name = 'Photo Attributes')
```

As to why: Not exist and not in operate differently in the presence of NULL

Not exists can early exit once a single occurrence is found, in doesn't.

Read up:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists
- [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)
- [Which is faster - NOT IN or NOT EXISTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500646/which-is-faster-not-in-or-not-exists)

Generally speaking: `not in` will not produce the desired results when Null is present; whereas not exists produces the desired results.  They behave differently.

Also the concat_ws() means an index can't be used and will be slower. so you may be able to optomize this as well.  But if it's good enough don't bother.

Comment: Changing `G.CLASSID` to `0+G.CLASSID` _might_ speed it up further.  (I don't know for sure.)  Also `INDEX(classic, type, name)` (in any order) may help.